# Include intermediate certificate in chain or not include?

Tags: ssl, certificate, tls1.2

We currently have a discussion wether it is the **servers** job to provide the **intermediate** certificate of a certificate chain in Apache's SSL configuration, **or**, if it is the client's job to already have the **intermediate** certificate in the local cert storage?

I'm not asking for opinion or recommend a tutorial.

I need to know how it is supposed to be configured according to official instructions.

Comment: The intermediate certificates only exist for the CA's own convenience. It is the server's responsibility to provide the complete certificate chain, and it is not the clients' responsibility to maintain anything beyond the trusted root certificate for each CA. Such a responsibility would not be feasible.

Comment: @user207421 I just stumbled upon my own old question. Your comment is the answer - it's the servers responsibility to provide the full chain, not the client's responsibility to keep track of and download every intermediate certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to our provider, the INTERMEDIATE certificate ought to be installed on the Apache server directly:

https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO6252

Not sure about others though.